Is gradient descent a greedy algorithm?
Gradient/steepest descent iteratively makes locally optimal decisions to minimize a function. At each iteration, it adjusts the parameters in the direction that minimizes the function the most, based on the gradient of the function at the current point.
This matches with the definition of the greedy algorithm paradigm, which states that a greedy algorithm is any algorithm that makes the locally optimal choice at each stage.
Can I state that gradient descent is a greedy algorithm?
